# SQL query to group data month wise in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have the output of my table in the below format.

select * from CAPACITY_MON.TABLESPACE_GROWTH_HIST where instance = 'MONDAY';

```
INSTANCE         TABLESPACE_NAME                TOTAL_SIZE TOTAL_USED TOTAL_FREE   MAX_FREE REPORT_DA
---------------- ------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
MONDAY           MONDAY_IDX                        3145728    2914624     231104     230400 27-MAR-18
MONDAY           SYSAUX                           14848000   14138112     709888     706560 27-MAR-18
MONDAY           SYSTEM                            2314240    2261120      53120      51200 27-MAR-18
MONDAY           MONDAY_DATA                        716800     456832     259968     259072 27-MAR-18
MONDAY           USERS                                5120       1984       3136       3136 27-MAR-18
MONDAY           MONDAY_DATA                       5242880    4236352    1006528    1005568 27-MAR-18
MONDAY           MONDAY_IDX                        3145728    2914624     231104     230400 28-MAR-18
MONDAY           SYSAUX                           14848000   14138688     709312     706560 28-MAR-18
MONDAY           SYSTEM                            2314240    2261120      53120      51200 28-MAR-18
MONDAY           MONDAY_DATA                        716800     456832     259968     259072 28-MAR-18
MONDAY           USERS                                5120       1984       3136       3136 28-MAR-18
MONDAY           MONDAY_DATA                       5242880    4236352    1006528    1005568 28-MAR-18
MONDAY           MONDAY_IDX                        3145728    2914624     231104     230400 29-MAR-18
MONDAY           SYSAUX                           14848000   14136896     711104     706560 29-MAR-18
MONDAY           SYSTEM                            2314240    2261120      53120      51200 29-MAR-18
MONDAY           MONDAY_DATA                        716800     456832     259968     259072 29-MAR-18
MONDAY           USERS                                5120       1984       3136       3136 29-MAR-18
MONDAY           MONDAY_DATA                       5242880    4236352    1006528    1005568 29-MAR-18
MONDAY           MONDAY_IDX                        3145728    2914624     231104     230400 30-MAR-18
MONDAY           SYSAUX                           14848000   14137152     710848     706560 30-MAR-18
MONDAY           SYSTEM                            2314240    2261120      53120      51200 30-MAR-18
MONDAY           MONDAY_DATA                        716800     456832     259968     259072 30-MAR-18
MONDAY           USERS                                5120       1984       3136       3136 30-MAR-18
MONDAY           MONDAY_DATA                       5242880    4236352    1006528    1005568 30-MAR-18
```

How do I get the above output in the below format

I need to get the max(TOTAL_USED) per tablespace per month. column should be based on the months like mentioned below.

```
TABLESPACE_NAME Mar-2018      Apr-2018
MONDAY_DATA         4236352       32655
MONDAY_IDX          2914624       212334
SYSTEM          2261120       23244
SYSAUX          14138688      123344
USERS           1984          3235666
```

I tried this query,

```
select TABLESPACE_NAME,max(TOTAL_USED),round(report_DATE,'month') from CAPACITY_MON.TABLESPACE_GROWTH_HIST where instance='MONDAY' group by TABLESPACE_NAME,report_date order by report_date;
```

It doesn't give the output as expected.

How could the above output be achieved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `TRUNC()` instead of `ROUND()` and group by that rather than by REPORT_DATE:

```
select TABLESPACE_NAME, max(TOTAL_USED), TRUNC(report_DATE, 'month') AS report_month
  from CAPACITY_MON.TABLESPACE_GROWTH_HIST 
 where instance = 'MOSA801M'
 group by TABLESPACE_NAME, TRUNC(report_date, 'MONTH');
```

Also the format you've specified in your question looks like you'd like the data pivoted. That's a bit more work but not difficult:

```
SELECT tablespace_name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN report_month = DATE'2018-03-01' THEN max_total_used END) AS "Mar-2018"
     , MAX(CASE WHEN report_month = DATE'2018-04-01' THEN max_total_used END) AS "Apr-2018"
  FROM (
    select TABLESPACE_NAME, max(TOTAL_USED) AS max_total_used, TRUNC(report_DATE, 'month') AS report_month
      from CAPACITY_MON.TABLESPACE_GROWTH_HIST 
     where instance = 'MOSA801M'
     group by TABLESPACE_NAME, TRUNC(report_date, 'MONTH')
) GROUP BY tablespace_name
 ORDER BY tablespace_name;
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** I think you might be able to derive the columns (but not their headers) "dynamically" as follows:

```
SELECT tablespace_name
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN report_month = TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'MONTH') THEN max_total_used END) AS "Last Month"
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN report_month = TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MONTH') THEN max_total_used END) AS "This Month"
  FROM (
    select TABLESPACE_NAME, max(TOTAL_USED) AS max_total_used, TRUNC(report_DATE, 'month') AS report_month
      from CAPACITY_MON.TABLESPACE_GROWTH_HIST 
     where instance = 'MOSA801M'
     group by TABLESPACE_NAME, TRUNC(report_date, 'MONTH')
) GROUP BY tablespace_name
 ORDER BY tablespace_name;
```

P.S. You could get dynamic column headers by using PL/SQL and dynamic SQL. But I think it is not really worth the effort.

Comment: I need to get the max(TOTAL_USED) per tablespace per month. column should be based on the months like mentioned below.
`TABLESPACE_NAME Mar-2018
MONDAY_DATA         4236352
MONDAY_IDX          2914624
SYSTEM          2261120
SYSAUX          14138688
USERS           1984`

Comment: That Works. Thank you. :)

Comment: Please upvote if my answer was useful to you, thanks!

Comment: I don't have privilege to upvote answers. I have accepted your answer instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TO_CHAR()` to get month from date

```
select TABLESPACE_NAME,
       max(TOTAL_USED) as 'Mar-2018',
       to_char(report_date, 'Month') AS report_Month
from CAPACITY_MON.TABLESPACE_GROWTH_HIST 
where instance='MOSA801M' and to_char(report_date, 'YYYY')='2018'
group by TABLESPACE_NAME,to_char(report_date, 'Month');
```

Comment: SQL> select TABLESPACE_NAME,
       max(TOTAL_USED),
       to_char(report_date, 'Month') AS report_Month
from CAPACITY_MON.TABLESPACE_GROWTH_HIST
where instance='MONDAY'
group by TABLESPACE_NAME,to_char(report_date, 'Month')
order by report_date;  2    3    4    5    6    7
order by report_date
         *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Remove order by and then check

Comment: Yes, The output looks good. But instead of column name max(TOTAL_USED), I would like to get the column name as month as mentioned in my main question. How could that be done!

Comment: `'Mar - 2018'` or `'April - 2018'` should be changed dynamically based on the output from report_month. 
we shouldn't declare it static.

Comment: @JayShankarGupta you'll want to include the year in the TO_CHAR() mask, otherwise that query can get data from past years as well

Comment: Edited my answer